# Ajax post to controller action gives "500 (Internal Server Error)" error in Chrome console

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am building a shopping cart and I have a successful method that adds items to the ShoppingCart. However, to remove these items I am using an Ajax call which is being unsuccessful and giving the following error:

```
POST http://localhost:62745/ShoppingCart/RemoveFromCart 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

the `remove` button-link should call the RemoveFromCart() method in the ShoppingCart Controller, receive a Json object and update several page elements. I tried suggestions on this forum, but they do not help: http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/discussions/244052

I also followed this tutorial for building the shopping cart: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-8

This is the Javascript in the Shopping Cart page:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Document.ready -> link up remove event handler
        $(".RemoveLink").click(function () {
            // Get the id from the link
            var recordToDelete = $(this).attr("data-id");
            if (recordToDelete != '') {
                // Perform the ajax post
                $.post("/ShoppingCart/RemoveFromCart", { "id": recordToDelete },
                    function (data) {
                        // Successful requests get here
                        // Update the page elements
                        if (data.ItemCount == 0) {
                            $('#row-' + data.DeleteId).fadeOut('slow');
                        } else {
                            $('#item-count-' + data.DeleteId).text(data.ItemCount);
                        }
                        $('#cart-total').text(data.CartTotal);
                        $('#update-message').text(data.Message);
                        $('#cart-status').text('Cart (' + data.CartCount + ')');
                    });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The remove link will be displayed with each new item in the ShoppingCart page on the fourth `<td>` column:

```
 @foreach (var item in Model.CartItems)
    {
        <tr id="row-@item.RecordId">
            <td>
                @item.Product.Name
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.Product.Price
            </td>
            <td id="item-count-@item.RecordId">
                @item.Count
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="#" class="RemoveLink" data-id="@item.RecordId">Remove</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

The following is the `RemoveFromCart` method in the ShoppingCartController that should be called in the javascript:

```
// AJAX: /ShoppingCart/RemoveFromCart/5
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult RemoveFromCart(int id)
        {
            var cart = ShoppingCart.GetShoppingCart(this.HttpContext);
            var productName = db.Carts.Single(c => c.ProductId == id).Product.Name;

            int itemCount = cart.RemoveItemFromCart(id);

            var results = new ShoppingCartRemoveViewModel
            {
                Message = Server.HtmlEncode(productName) +
                    " has been removed from your shopping cart.",
                CartTotal = cart.GetTotal(),
                CartCount = cart.GetCount(),
                ItemCount = itemCount,
                DeleteId = id
            };

            return Json(results);
        }
```

Comment: you'll have to debug your controller action.

Comment: The only reason I can imagine is that your javascript is mixed in view so it is creating an array and trying to pass array instead of single value

If you are sure that everything is good with passed parameter and that you pass single integer, keep in mind that jquery .attr returns string, not int. It doesn't really matter because it should be parsed by ASP.NET MVC data binder.

However you can try Parsing passed value to Int with jquery, or change id type in your method from int to type of string.

Comment: `500 (Internal Server Error)` means the controller method is throwing an exception. Use you browser tools - the Network Tab - to inspect the response which will give the details of the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a mistake in the RemoveFromCart() method.This method takes a parameter of the Cart object's RecordId which is the primary key of a cart item being removed. I was assuming the parameter to the method to be the ProductId attribute of the cart table:

`var productName = db.Carts.Single(c => c.ProductId == id).Product.Name;`

I changed `c.ProductId` to `c.RecordId`since being the primary key of the Cart table, it would allow me to get the Product Name from a cart item which is being removed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to call the Action passing the id as part of the body of the post request. If you look at the comment just above the action `// AJAX: /ShoppingCart/RemoveFromCart/5` you'll see that the router is expecting it to be part of the url.

Try changing

```
$.post("/ShoppingCart/RemoveFromCart/", { "id": recordToDelete }
```

to

```
$.post("/ShoppingCart/RemoveFromCart/"+recordToDelete,
```

Comment: It doesn't matter in this situation. It would only if he had 'FromBody' next to binded id parameter